# Disable split screen functionality

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have developed quiz mobile website dynamicquiz.tk . I want that if a user uses split screen functionality to search for an answer on Google then, the quiz should terminate. Is there any JavaScript event that is fired when split screen is used, or is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean by "split screen"? If the user has multiple browser windows open, or multiple tabs? Even if you could control that, you would never be able to prevent users e.g. from using Firefox with your quiz and Chrome to Google the results. Honestly, I don't think what you are planning is doable.

Comment: There is a new feature in Android nougat to use multiple apps simultaneously ,just like Samsung's multitasking feature .... I do not want my app to be used simultaneously with other browser

Comment: Pretty sure nothing like this is supported by browsers alone ...

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that this concerns mobile devices only, you should include that info in your question :-)

Comment: Can i identify it in ionic app ??